# How to avoid annoying `auto-fill` behaviour in `c-mode` comment?

Tags: cc-mode, auto-fill-mode

Recently I write quite a lot comments for c/c++ files. I use [`auto-fill-mode`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode) for comment auto format. But I found a quite annoying problem: whenever I input <kbd>SPC</kbd> at the end of a comment line, the cursor just sticks to the end of the last word in the line, as the screenshot shows below:

[image: auto-fill in c block comment]

Strangely, this only happens in block style `/**/` comment. If I use line comment `//`, `auto-fill` won't prevent cursor from moving:

[image: auto-fill in c line comment]

Since I made the screenshot with `emacs -q`, I am sure this is the default behaviour of `auto-fill-mode` with `emacs 26.2`. Can anyone tell me how to prevent such annoying default behaviour?

Comment: With more debugging, I found this only happens when the last line of block comment is ` * */`.